# Group and reduce Elements

Tags: java, java-stream

My database is returning a DataSet like this

result

```
id  Percentage
1    20
1    15
2    30
2    40
3    10
```

that is mapped to a Contract entity

```
class Contract{
    private Integer id;
    private Double percentaje;
    ....
}
```

my expected result is having Map<Integer, String>

for example : 1, 20% 15%

the first value is the id, and the second is concat of the percentage

this is my approach so far

```
Map<Integer, String> res = result.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Contract::getId,
Collectors.reducing(0, Contract::getPercentage, (a, b) -> String.join("% ", a.toString(), b.toString()))
    );
```

intellij show me an error

`Bad return type in lambda expression: String cannot be converted to Number & Comparable<? extends Number & Comparable<?>>`

Any idea how to solve this, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with [`Collectors.mapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) as downstream of `Collectors.groupingBy()`:

```
Map<Integer, String> result = result.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Contract::getId,
                        Collectors.mapping(c -> c.getPercentage().toString() + "%", Collectors.joining(" "))));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue:

> Bad return type in lambda expression: String cannot be converted to Number & Comparable>

might be with the Collectors.reducing call.

It should be:

```
Collectors.reducing(
   "",  // Contract to default String
   contract -> contract.getPercentage().toString() + "%",  // mapping Contract to String 
   (a, b) -> String.join(" ", a, b)  // reducing two ready-mapped Strings
)
```

compare to the declaration of [`Collectors.reducing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-U-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
public static <T,U> Collector<T,?,U> reducing(
   U identity,
   Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper,
   BinaryOperator<U> op
)
```

where `U` is your output type `String`, and `T` is your input type `Contract`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this could have been done directly from the Database as well, but this work for Java 8.

```java
    List<Contract> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(new Contract(1, 20));
    result.add(new Contract(1, 15));
    result.add(new Contract(2, 30));
    result.add(new Contract(2, 40));
    result.add(new Contract(3, 10));
        
    Map<Integer, String> mapped = new HashMap<>();
        
    result.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Contract::getId)).forEach((k, l) -> 
        mapped.put(k, l.stream().map(c -> c.getPercentaje().toString().concat("% ")).collect(Collectors.joining())
        )
    );
        
    mapped.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ", " + v));
```

The result of `Collectors.groupingBy` is a `Map<Integer, List<Contract>>`. While it should be possible to do a 'one liner', I think is easier to understand by looping through the first map and add the result "reduction" to a different map.

Just for completness, the query for this result in MySQL is as follows

```sql
SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(t2.percentaje, '%') SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM table1 t1 
    JOIN table1 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

`GROUP_CONCAT` is a pretty useful function for these case scenarios. You can read further in [the documentation for it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat). (Thanks to hc_dev)

I think both of these approaches can be further optimized, specially the query.

Java fiddle [here](https://paiza.io/projects/aIWZog8Rw-33mnGqNhwbYw).
SQL fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84bc3ddf0c29bb10efb73fad54d1b143).

Comment: The load-directly approach is pretty straight forward. Add some link to the MySQL docs [`GROUP_CONCAT(expr)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate-function.